# jQuery autocomplete with matching unordered multiple words

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I am using this version for the jQuery autocomplete where I have a list of words :

http://jsfiddle.net/K6Dt2/7/

```
$(function () {
var availableTags = [
    "hello world", "foo bar", "bar foo world", "hello", "bar"
];
function customFilter(array, terms) {
    arrayOfTerms = terms.split(" ");
    var term = $.map(arrayOfTerms, function (tm) {
         return $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(tm);
    }).join('|');
   var matcher = new RegExp("\\b" + term, "i");
    return $.grep(array, function (value) {
       return matcher.test(value.label || value.value || value);
    });
};
$("#tags").autocomplete({
    source: availableTags,
    multiple: false,
    mustMatch: false
    ,source: function (request, response) {
        // delegate back to autocomplete, but extract the last term
        response(customFilter(
        availableTags, request.term));
    },
});
});
```

> "hello world", "foo bar", "bar foo world", "hello", "bar"

My problem is that I would like to display only "hello world" when typing "world hello" for example.

Also when I type an space, all options are displayed which is incorrect in my case.

How can I achieve this behaviour ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

forgetting highlighting, you could try iteratively grepping your array for splitted terms

```
function customFilter(array, terms) {
    arrayOfTerms = terms.split(" ");

    arrayOfTerms.forEach(function (entry) {
        array = $.grep(array, function (e) {
            return e.indexOf(entry) >= 0;
        })
    });

    return array;
}
```